# Double confirmation program exiting

Tags: c#

somehow i dont know my program needs a second confirmation to exit...how can i remove it?

```
private void MainProg_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Θέλετε πραγματικά να κλείσει η εφαρμογή?",
        "Κλείσιμο", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes )
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: maybe the question is hidden within the text of the message box

Comment: "Do you really want to close the application?"

Comment: yes...i just dont need second confirmation

Comment: remove all the code you've written and your program will close without asking a confirmation... if that's what you're asking

Comment: i need only one confirmation...the second is useless....its the same window twice

Comment: you're probably showing the same balloon somewhere else in your code, the code you've written shows only once the confirmation. Are you sure you haven't registered twice to the closing event?

Comment: You are calling Application.Exit() while the application is already exiting.  You are helping too much.  Remove the Application.Exit() call.  Fwiw, the user is already 100% sure that he didn't click the Close button by accident.  You are helping too much.

Comment: thx Hans Passant..... that was it....

Comment: i replaced " if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes )
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }"

with 

if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

and everythings runs perfect now...thx again

Comment: but now the window close but the application keep running in Debug mode :/

Comment: what about now @HansPassant? need help...i have a time limit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `Application.Exit` causes a second call to `MainProg_FormClosing`.  Exiting the application is handled automatically; the call to `Application.Exit` is unnecessary.

You can simply remove the call to `Application.Exit` to prevent the second confirmation dialog:

```
DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Θέλετε πραγματικά να κλείσει η εφαρμογή?",
    "Κλείσιμο", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

---

Edited to add:

If you need to call `Application.Exit` (e.g., multiple message pumps), you can suppress the dialog if the form is being closed due to an `Application.Exit` call:

```
private void MainProg_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Add this line:
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall) return;

    // remainder of code as in original:
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Θέλετε πραγματικά να κλείσει η εφαρμογή?",
        "Κλείσιμο", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes )
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but now the window close but the application keep running in Debug mode :/

Comment: You are the BEST....thats it......everything forks like a charm now....thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're callng `FormClosing` when using `Application.Exit` because `Application.Exit` also call`FormClosing` so you need to do this

```
DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Θέλετε πραγματικά να κλείσει η εφαρμογή?",
        "Κλείσιμο", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
```